# How to get reverse of a series of elements using Enumarable in C#?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, enumerable

I have two Integer variables like

```
int Max = 10;
int limit = 5;
```

and a Dictionary

```
Dictionary<String , String> MyDict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

I need to fill the dictionary with `Max` elements and if the index is greater than or equal to `limit` then the value should be none.

Here is my sample code which will clear my question

```
int j = 1;
for (int i = Max-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (i >= limit)
        MyDict.Add((j++).ToString(), "None");
    else
        MyDict.Add((j++).ToString(), i.ToString());
}
```

so the result will be like

```
{ "1" "None" }   
{ "2" "None" }   
{ "3" "None" }    
{ "4" "None" }
{ "5" "None" }
{ "6" "4" }
{ "7" "3" }
{ "8" "2" }
{ "9" "1" }
{ "10" "0" }
```

How to do this using `LINQ` or `LAMBDA Expression`

The reverse can be done using `Enumarable` here it is

```
MyDict  = Enumerable.Range(0, Max)
                    .ToDictionary(X => (X + 1).ToString(), X => X >= limit ? "None" : X.ToString());
```

Output of this expression

```
{ "1" "0" }
{ "2" "1" }
{ "3" "2" }
{ "4" "3" }
{ "5" "4" }
{ "6" "None" }
{ "7" "None" }
{ "8" "None" }
{ "9" "None" }
{ "10" "None" }
```

But how to do the reverse of this (like the output of the `for` loop)? Or how can I modify the existing `LINQ`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what exactly want to achieve? You appear to be using the word "reverse" in two different meanings in the same question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Enumerable.Range(0, Max).OrderByDescending(x => x).ToDictionary(x => (Max - x).ToString(), x => x >= limit ? "None" : x.ToString());
```

Comment: Your coworkers or six-month older self will give you -10 for the one-liner