# How to get Alternate elements using Enumerable in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, enumerable

This is a continuation of my question: [How to get reverse of a series of elements using Enumarable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123274/how-to-get-reverse-of-a-series-of-elements-using-enumarable-in-c)

Now I need alternate elements only. Here is my solution using `for` loop:

```
int Max = 10;
int limit = 5;
Dictionary<String , String> MyDict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <Max; i++)
{
    if (i >= limit)
        MyDict.Add((i+1).ToString(), "None");
    else
        MyDict.Add((i+1).ToString(), j.ToString());
    j+=2;
}
```

The output is like

```
{ "1" "0"}
{ "2" "2"}
{ "3" "4"}
{ "4" "6"}
{ "5" "8"}
{ "6" "None"}
{ "7" "None"}
{ "8" "None"}
{ "9" "None"}
{ "10" "None"}
```

How to do this using `Enumarerable` or Using any LINQ method. And also the reverse like my previous question: [How to get reverse of a series of elements using Enumarable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123274/how-to-get-reverse-of-a-series-of-elements-using-enumarable-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use the standard LINQ `Where` extension method as a basis for doing what you need.

Given a list of `IEnumerable<T>` it would work like this:

```
var evens = list.Where((t, i) => i % 2 == 0);
var odds = list.Where((t, i) => i % 2 == 1);
```

Hopefully you can build on these to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
int max = 10;
int limit = 5;

var dict = Enumerable.Range(1, max)
                     .ToDictionary(x => x.ToString(),
                                   x => (x > limit) ? "None"
                                                    : ((x - 1) * 2).ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a standard LINQ method that does this.  But you can create custom IEnumerable extension methods to do this sort of thing.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981895.aspx

Alternate elements is one of the examples here.  Basically it's just taking your example code and packaging it as an extension so you get the syntax you want.