# Convert a C# string array to a dictionary

Tags: c#

Is there an elegant way of converting this string array:

```
string[] a = new[] {"name", "Fred", "colour", "green", "sport", "tennis"};
```

into a Dictionary such that every two successive elements of the array become one {key, value} pair of the dictionary (I mean {"name" -> "Fred", "colour" -> "green", "sport" -> "tennis"})?

I can do it easily with a loop, but is there a more elegant way, perhaps using LINQ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123685/how-to-get-alternate-elements-using-enumerable-in-c-sharp). At least, the solutions will probably be virtually the same.

Comment: I fixed your syntax; it didn't compile before.

Comment: Another [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269847/select-even-odd-elements-in-ienumerablet) that may help you. Contains itself links to other helpful questions it was marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who contributed answers and links to similar questions. There are some interesting and thought-provoking ideas here. My favourite answers are Turbot's and digEmAll's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this ?

```
    var q = a.Zip(a.Skip(1), (Key, Value) => new { Key, Value })
             .Where((pair,index) => index % 2 == 0)
             .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
```

Comment: This is going through the list twice. That would be a problem for IEnumerable (I know question was about array) also, it is doing extra work.

Answer (score 5):

```
var dict = a.Select((s, i) => new { s, i })
            .GroupBy(x => x.i / 2)
            .ToDictionary(g => g.First().s, g => g.Last().s);
```

Answer (score 4):

Since it's an array I would do this:

```
var result = Enumerable.Range(0,a.Length/2)
                       .ToDictionary(x => a[2 * x], x => a[2 * x + 1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a simular method to handle this type of request. But since your array contains both keys and values i think you need to split this first.

Then you can use something like this to combine them

```
public static IDictionary<T, T2> ZipMyTwoListToDictionary<T, T2>(IEnumerable<T> listContainingKeys, IEnumerable<T2> listContainingValue)
    {
        return listContainingValue.Zip(listContainingKeys, (value, key) => new { value, key }).ToDictionary(i => i.key, i => i.value);
    }
```

Comment: Some suggestions: the name is misleading, call it `ZipToDictionary` (there are no lists involved). And use descriptive type elements, i.e. `TKey, TValue`

Comment: So how do you get from the array to the two enumerables?

Comment: I just added [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12426649/1159478) which uses this general idea, but expands on it to solve the problem I previously mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
a.Select((input, index) = >new {index})
  .Where(x=>x.index%2!=0)
  .ToDictionary(x => a[x.index], x => a[x.index+1])
```

I would recommend using a for loop but I have answered as requested by you.. This is by no means neater/cleaner..

Answer (score 0):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> EveryOther<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    bool shouldReturn = true;
    foreach (T item in source)
    {
        if (shouldReturn)
            yield return item;
        shouldReturn = !shouldReturn;
    }
}

public static Dictionary<T, T> MakeDictionary<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    return source.EveryOther()
        .Zip(source.Skip(1).EveryOther(), (a, b) => new { Key = a, Value = b })
        .ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
}
```

The way this is set up, and because of the way `Zip` works, if there are an odd number of items in the list the last item will be ignored, rather than generation some sort of exception.

Note: derived from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12426403/1159478)

Answer (score 0):

```
IEnumerable<string> strArray = new string[] { "name", "Fred", "colour", "green", "sport", "tennis" };


            var even = strArray.ToList().Where((c, i) => (i % 2 == 0)).ToList();
            var odd = strArray.ToList().Where((c, i) => (i % 2 != 0)).ToList();

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = even.ToDictionary(x => x, x => odd[even.IndexOf(x)]);
```