# Reading text file into two arrays C#(Edited)

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files, streamreader

**To clarify, I want all the odd lines of the text file read to an array called `cPhone` and all the even lines read to an array called `cName`.This is not reading from an array to two separate arrays, but from a text file and creating those arrays. I should have been more clear in the original question, so hopefully this makes a difference.**

While it may appear that this question has been answered, I have searched for 3 nights now, across multiple sites and can't find something that helps me. And not just helps, but explains why it works (I want to learn, not just copy).

I want to read a text file into two arrays that I can use later. Shortened version of the list below:

```
0884006750
Blazing Fire
0350237000
Iron Engineering
0798726565
Custom Couture
```

I'd like to have all the phone numbers in one array and the business names in the other, but I am at a loss how to do this and think there has to be a simple answer. I've seen a LOT of answers about delimeters, and I understand that I could do this easily if they were on the same line separated by a comma or space, but I don't know that it can work with this file. I am new to programming, but I've tried the solutions I've found and nothing seems to work, either that or I don't understand what I've read.

This is what I'm trying to work with, but I'm getting an exception. I've tried changing the order and all.

```
string cCustomer = "customer.txt";
string[] cName = new string[0];
int[] cPhone = new int[0];

private void SplitArray()
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;
    StreamReader fileSR = new StreamReader(cCustomer);    
    line = fileSR.ReadLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
        cPhone[counter] = int.Parse(fileSR.ReadLine());
        cName[counter] = line;
        counter ++;
        line = fileSR.ReadLine();
    }
    fileSR.Close();                              

    for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        phoneComboBox.Items.Add(cPhone[i]);
    }       

}
```

Chances are there is a lot wrong with this as I've never attempted this properly before, I've always had instructions to follow. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141241/selecting-alternate-items-of-an-array-c-sharp (PS took me 10 seconds to find that one)

Comment: In your file is it always 1 line for a number followed by 1 line for a name?

Comment: @DavidG Why not cv-dup it? Oh, and *waves*

Comment: ok, obviously my search skills suck, thanks.

Comment: @Jaqtaris No downvote for you, since you just made me laugh :)

Comment: doesn't explain why in that answer, but this can be marked as a duplicate

Comment: Why two arrays?  Why not create a `Business` class or similar that contains the `BusinessName` and `PhoneNumber` properties?  Keeping data in sync across multiple arrays is rarely a good idea.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling I'm usually a touch mroe careful when using the dupe hammer :)

Comment: @DarrenYoung Eh, could be a class assignment.

Comment: It does not answer the question. In the post that @DavidG linked, it is about separating an already existing array. Which is not the whole story and not the only way to do this.
I think this code has a different aproach and should be answered with the current aproach.

Comment: @DavidG Oh, you've got a gold in c#? No wonder... I'd feel the same way.

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Well, it's done now!

Comment: @LynnCrumbling part of a class assignment, but i'm trying to understand how and why, not just do it

Comment: @Jaqtaris That's great; you don't want to have "programmers" that just grab code off the internet and copy it into place without understanding it. :) Darren was trying to point out that "in the real world", you'd be better off taking another approach. I figured that you were handed a snippet of a data file and asked specifically to work with it as two arrays.

Comment: @sokkyoku sorry, I missed your comment. Yes it does continue like this

Comment: Let me know if you still want to read line by line and store directly into two arrays as you read then, but you might be able to simply use `Where` on your `StreamReader`, not sure.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37703675/5565414 this answer was added to the thread @DavidG linked to and it works! I also understand it, so even better