# How get odd chars from String in C#

Tags: c#, string

I am new to C#. My problem is to take *odd chars* from a `string` and get a new `string` from those odds.

```
string name = "Filip"; // expected output ="Flp"
```

I don't want to take, for example,

```
string result = name.Substring(0, 1) + name.Substring(2, 1) + ... etc.
```

I need a function for this operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selecting alternate items of an array C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20141241/selecting-alternate-items-of-an-array-c-sharp)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try *Linq* (you actually want *even* characters since `string` is *zero-based*):

```
string name = "Filip";
string result = string.Concat(name.Where((c, i) => i % 2 == 0));
```

In case of good old loop implementation, I suggest *building* the `string` with a help of `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name.Length / 2 + 1);

for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i += 2)
  sb.Append(name[i]);

string result = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Yeah thats correct, thanks a lot ;) I will accept it in 10 minutes ;)