# C# - fair team allocation with ratings

Tags: c#, list, rating

I have a list of rankings for players in a sport and would like to assign them to teams so that the distribution of ratings is as fair as possible (i.e. eliminating teams with lots of high rated players and vice versa).

Currently I am doing this but it doesn't seem to give the optimal solution:

```
ratingList.Sort();
ratingList.Reverse();

var team1List = ratingList.Where((r, i) => i % 2 != 0).ToList();
var team2List = ratingList.Where((r, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get Alternate elements using Enumerable in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4123685/how-to-get-alternate-elements-using-enumerable-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

After sorting them in descending order try this

```
var team1List = ratingList.Where((r, i) => i % 2 != 0).ToList();
var team2List = ratingList.Where((r, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToList();
```

Comment: This will not work you should put 0 and 9 in first team, not 0 and 8 at least this was expain by the op.

Comment: what do you mean by 0 and 9?

Comment: @Alby, I think he means if you have 10 ratings (players) then based on the description you would like to have 0 and 9 (based on rankings) players in one team. But I guess the idea of the question is just to have an even (fair) distribution

Comment: Yes the requirements of the op is to have first player[index 0] with last player[index 9] in one team. Your code doesn't do that.

Comment: I would like my code to give a fair distribution of rankings into each team. (the teams here being 2 lists of the ratings)

Comment: is it possible to have an odd number of items in the ratingList? Meaning that you will end up with one team having one player more than the other ?

Answer (score 0):

For the optimal solution, the idea is to consider the `ratingList` twice side by side 
`ascending` vs `descending` and take the first half (the other one is just mirrored)

```
Ex:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4 | 5, 6, 7, 8, 9
9, 8, 7, 6, 5 | 4, 3, 2, 1, 0

and keep the first half

team1 team2 team1 team2 |
0,    1,    2,    3,    | 4 team1
9,    8,    7,    6,    | 5 team2
```

The evens go in `team1` and the odds in `team2`. If we have an even number of pairs, the last pair will be redistributed between the two teams (also please note that this works only for `ratingList >= 4` (it's up to you to handle for less). Also for even number of ratings I propose to exclude the middle rating and decide later what to do with it.

Considering all the above, the solution should look like this

```
ratingList.Sort();
var count = ratingList.Count();

// if even number of players, keep aside the one in the middle (as rating)
int? middle = null;
if (count % 2 != 0)
{
    middle = ratingList[count / 2];
    ratingList.RemoveAt(count / 2);
}

var ratingListDesc = ratingList.OrderByDescending(i => i).ToList();

var half = count / 2;
var take = half % 2 != 0 ? half - 1 : half;

var team1List = ratingList.Take(take).Where((r, i) => i % 2 == 0).ToList();
team1List.AddRange(ratingListDesc.Take(take).Where((r, i) => i % 2 == 0));

var team2List = ratingList.Take(take).Where((r, i) => i % 2 != 0).ToList();
team2List.AddRange(ratingListDesc.Take(take).Where((r, i) => i % 2 != 0));

// we just have to redistribute the remaining pair between each team
if (half % 2 != 0)
{
     team1List.Add(ratingList[half - 1]);
     team2List.Add(ratingListDesc[half - 1]);
}

if (middle.HasValue)
{
    // do something, or not ...
}
```